# Linq - select all rows from database

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got code:

```
var achievments = db.Achievments.Where(ac => ac.ApplicationId == AppId && ac.Player.StrId == PlayerStrId).Select
            (a =>

            new AchResult
                {
                    id = a.Id,
                    achType = a.AchievmentType,
                    description = a.Description,
                    name = a.Name,
                    revealedIconUrl = a.RevealedIconUrl,
                    totalSteps = a.TotalSteps,
                    unlockedIconUrl = a.UnlockedIconUrl,
                    state = a.InitialState
                });
```

When i set breakpoint before **var achievment= (...)** and look to sql visualizer, select query doesn't contain any filter like **where**. But later, when i retrieve the returned rows i've got rows with where clausule applied. 
How build this query to generate sql to get only data meets **where** condtion.

I return this from method as IEnumerable.

It's something about queryable ?

Comment: What is the declared type of `db.Achievments` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell db is context, and Achievments is my dbSet. I use Entity Framework and Sql Express Server.

Comment: That's kinda weird, then; that *should* compose cleanly (i.e. the `where` in the SQL). What tool are you using to monitor the SQL?

Comment: @MarcGravell aghhhhh i think i know what is wrong. i look on db.Achievments value so it doesn't contain where clausule.

Comment: @MarcGravell But i read some article about difference between queryable and enumerable in linq to entity queries. How prevent from get all rows from database and apply filter to memory-in rows set?

Comment: Since the type of `db.Achievements` is `DbSet<T>`, it should already be using the `IQueryable<T>` version of `Where`, i.e. `Queryable.Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> ...)`, in which case it should *already* be composing correctly. So again: how and where are you monitoring the SQL?

Comment: @MarcGravell this is fragment from asp.net blog: "Starting with Beta2 of Visual Studio 2008 you can use a new LINQ to SQL visualizer plug-in to easily see (and test out) any LINQ to SQL query expression.  Simply set a breakpoint and then hover over a LINQ to SQL query and click the magnify glass to pull up its expression visualizer within the debugger"

Comment: And what are you clicking on to do that? Also keeping in mind that this *isn't LINQ-to-SQL* ;p Frankly, I don't think that is a reliable way to test this. To monitor what actually gets sent, you should use an intercepting logger (something like mini-profiler), or a sql-trace. I suspect it is working just fine, but it is the approach you are using to look at the sql that is failing.

Comment: Or use EF 6, which will allow you to easily log the resultant queries.  You should be able to place `db.Database.Log=Debug.Write` before, and you should start seeing the SQL being output in your debug window.